# pytest mock failing when mocking function from imported package

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

pytest-mock is properly installed:

```
> pip list | grep pytest
pytest                7.4.2
pytest-mock           3.14.0
```

This unit test passes with success:

```py
import pytest

class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def get_a() -> A:
    return A(1)

@pytest.fixture
def mocked_A(mocker):
    a = A(2)
    mocker.patch(f"{__name__}.get_a", return_value=a)

def test_mocked_a(mocked_A) -> None:
    a = get_a()
    assert a.value == 2
```

Now, if I move A and get_A to mypackage.mymodule, mocking stops to work.

```py
import pytest

# note: these imports work: mypackage is correctly installed
from mypackage.mymodule import A, get_a

@pytest.fixture
def mocked_A(mocker):
    a = A(2)
    mocker.patch("mypackage.mymodule.get_a", return_value=a)

def test_mocked_a(mocked_A) -> None:
    a = get_a()
    assert a.value == 2
```

The test fails with this error:

```
mocked_A = None

    def test_mocked_a(mocked_A) -> None:
        a = get_a()
>       assert a.value == 2
E       assert 1 == 2
E        +  where 1 = <mypackage.mymodule.A object at 0x7f063e3f2c80>.value

test_a.py:13: AssertionError
=============================================================================== short test summary info ================================================================================
FAILED test_a.py::test_mocked_a - assert 1 == 2
```

Looks like get_a has not been mocked. Anything I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike imported modules/packages `get_a` is an ordinary identifier that points to the function that you want to patch without looking it up in `mypackage.mymodule`, as this is already done during the import. So in this case you have to patch it directly via `f"{__name__}.get_a"` like in your first test. This is not a special behavior of `pytest-mock`.

Comment: That works, but I am confused. If the first argument is not the "import path" of the callable, then why is it a string and not directly the callable ?

Comment: For my concrete use case things break down. I am not testing `get_a` directly, but a function which calls `get_a`. It looks like by mocking in the test module `f"{__name__}.get_a"`, the call of `get_a` done in the tested function is not patched.

Comment: oh, issue was that my `get_a` function was decorated. (I do not delete these comments in case someone also has issues with decorated functions)